# how to use split function in where used LIKE operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want use function split in my query that contain **LIKE** operator.

```
 SELECT * FROM Tbl_News n WHERE n.Date >= @Fromdate AND n.Date <= @Todate 
 AND n.Title LIKE '%' + (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitString(@key, ',')) + '%'
```

type n.Title is nvarchar.
but raise this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `APPLY`:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM Tbl_News n CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitString(@key, ',')) s(item)
WHERE n.Date >= @Fromdate AND
      n.Date <= @Todate AND 
      n.Title LIKE '%' + s.item + '%' ;
```

You might consider using a full text index on title, if you care about performance.

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, looks like the subquery `(SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitString(@key, ','))` gives multiple results - I guess it would do when `@key` contains commas.

You can't use a query that returns multiple results in a LIKE clause - maybe you don't want to split the string, or you want to query around each split value - in which case, see Gordon's answer.